# Accessing session in ASP.NET app via Context

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, multithreading, task

I have a mvc action method, similar to the below construct.

```
public ActionResult About()
{
    System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session["testValue"] = "about";
    ViewBag.Message = "Your application description page.";

    var sc = SynchronizationContext.Current;

    Task t = Task.Run(( ) => {

        string sessionValue = null;

        sc.Post((state)=> {
            //How do I access Session value here ?

        },null);


    });

    return View();
}
```

I'm wondering how I access the "Session Value" in `sc.Post` method ? Basically, when the new thread starts, it needs to access the HttpSession of the parent.

Comment: What are you actually trying to achieve?

Comment: @PatrickHofman: Sorry, updated the question with my ask.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the `Session` is derived from the current thread, you have to inject the session from the originating request thread:

```
var session = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session;
```

Then use `session` inside your thread delegate. Note that the session can be destructed in the meantime if the originating request is terminated.

```
session["testValue"] = "abc";
```

Comment: But, how do I get the value from `state` parameter ? In the code sample, after `sc.post` I'm stuck up how do i get the session value

Comment: You are injecting `null` there, so why do you want to get the `state`?

Comment: May be I am not explaining it clear. `t` is a new thread that is running parallel along with existing main thread. My intention is to access the session inside the thread because this thread `t` cannot access the main thread session. So, I save `SyncronizationContext` in a variable `sc` and I try to access that from the thread (by keeping sc global or passing it along to the thread). Now, `sc.post` will read the session data and in callback it passes the data to the thread. I'm stuck at that point.

Comment: `sc.Post((state)=> { var x = session["abc"]; },null);`

Comment: Got it.. thank you. So, after `sc.post` the `current thread's session` is mapped to its parent session.  so, accessing the values set in parent session works. Is my understanding correct ?

Comment: No, you are just passing along a variable.

Comment: Ok, so I store the parent session in a variable called `sc` and I pass it along to the newly invoked thread. And from the thread I access the stored session values. Right ?

Comment: In theory, inside `sc.Post` you are already kind of "on request thread", so should be able to access session as usual.